# How to add number line before multiline Textview in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I have recently seen an Android app in which number line was added before each line in separate Column .The main column is also scrolling along with multiline TextView.How to add such line numbers along with textview ? See the Screenshot :

[image]

I have tried to implement it by adding 2 multiline textview with equal fontsize.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ct"
        android:layout_weight="0.075"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:background="#303133"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#303133">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But how to add same number of line in NumberLine TextView according to other Textview ? and how to scroll NumberLine TextView along with other Textview ? afterall is there any other way to implement same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use two [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) , one for line number , the other one for the code, where each line is a item.

A [tutorial](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/09/android-recyclerview-tutorial.html) for example.

**EDIT**

I think you can use a second Scroll view for you text , for example :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_ct"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.075"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#303133">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/ct"
                 android:layout_weight="match_parent"
                 android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                 android:background="#303133"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                 android:textSize="15sp"/>
       </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_txt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#303133">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and then coordinate the scroll listener

```
scrollViewCT.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            scrollViewTxt.scrollTo(scrollx, scrollY)
        }
    });

scrollViewTxt.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                scrollViewCT.scrollTo(scrollx, scrollY)
            }
        });
```

**Another solution** is to have directly the two text views in the same scrollview , maybe something like that:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#303133">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ct"
                android:layout_weight="0.075"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:background="#303133"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how to add line number in that also ? I think Layout does not matters

Comment: What do you mean ? are your speaking for a app or in android studio ?

Comment: I have already described way to implement its layout. question is to know mechanism so that number textview also scrolls with main textview . Implementing RecyclerView does not solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getLineCount() in TextView to get the actual number of lines that are displayed on the screen for the current textview.

The getLineCount() works after the layout has been measured and drawn, otherwise it return 0. So you can use the method, the following way, which will notify you when a layout change happens to the TextViw :

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // call textview.getLineCount() ;
    }
});
```